# Noob issue on 'Not Recognized' in Shell

Tags: python, django, command-line

I recently installed python & Django & was going through the [Command Line Crash Course.](http://cli.learncodethehardway.org/book/) But I'm getting stuck at the beginning. When I type in simple things like 'pwd" or 'hostname' it returns:

when I use the shell command prompt and type in pwd this is what I get:

'pwd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

---

Any Tips on What I Should Do?

Comment: I guess that's because you are in Python shell, where there are no built in or PATHd tools like pwd?

Comment: `pwd` and `hostname` are shell commands

Comment: `Any tips on what I should do?` - YES, show the relevant code.

Comment: I don't know what the *Command Line Crash Course* is (your link is broken), but it looks like it's walking you through shell commands. In that case, don't run `python` yet. If you post a valid link, you can get better help.

Comment: Probably http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/appendixa.html . And yes, if you see `>>>`, you're on the Python command line, not the shell command line. Press control-D to get back to the shell command line (where `pwd` does work).

Comment: @lurker i just edited the link

Comment: That link has nothing to do with Python. Why is this a Python question?

Answer (score 0):

From your link:

```
This book is a crash course in using the **command line** to make your computer perform tasks
```

That book is not about python, is about shell.
Your shell looks like:

```
some/random/path$'here i type commands'
```

ie

```
some/random/path$ pwd
```

If your console starts with '>>>' you are in python. Either type exit() and enter or press CTRL+D to go back to console.